# Nested IF statement PHP

Tags: php

after a bit of adivce -I have a rather lengthy chunk of nested if statement, and I'm looking at ways I can refine it and make it more efficient. I did think of a switch - but I can't see how I could split this up.

Any thoughts appreciated

```
  $portfolioItems [$i] = array(//assign vars into array
  'imagePath' => '/sites/jda_redev/'.$myrow_home->path.'/thumbs/thumbs_'.$myrow_home->filename,
  'altText' => $myrow_home->alttext,
  'description' => $myrow_home->description,
  'client' => $extra_client->field_value,
  'job' => $extra_job->field_value,
  'channel' => $extra_channel->field_value,
  'channeltwo' => $extra_channeltwo->field_value,
  'channelthree' => $extra_channelthree->field_value,
  'channelfour' => $extra_channelfour->field_value,
  'channelfive' => $extra_channelfive->field_value,
  'sector' => $extra_sector->field_value,
  'workerone' => $extra_workerone->field_value,
  'workertwo' => $extra_workertwo->field_value,
  'gallery' => $galleryName,
  'mediaType' => $media_type->field_value,
  'videoName' => $video_name->field_value
  );

if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['imagePath'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['imagePath'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['altText'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['altText'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['description'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['description'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['client'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['client'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['job'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['job'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['channel'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['channel'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['channeltwo'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['channeltwo'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['channelthree'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['channelthree'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['channelfour'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['channelfour'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['channelfive'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['channelfive'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['sector'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['sector'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['workerone'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['workerone'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['workertwo'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['workertwo'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['gallery'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['gallery'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['mediaType'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['mediaType'] = " ";}
      if ( $portfolioItems [$i]['videoName'] == "" )
      {$portfolioItems [$i]['videoName'] = " ";}
```

Comment: do you have more items in $portfolioItems [$i] not listed here? or are you wanting to do this for the whole array?

Comment: why don't you add values('mediaType','videoName') to an array and loop the if statement using the for loop?

Comment: are there more options in the portfolioItem[$i]['more options here']? or are you checking all the options individually?

Comment: I feel sorry for your fingers that you ever typed something like this out!

Comment: @Dan Grossman - isn't that what interns are for? :)

Comment: sorry people, should be clearer now - added in the section where I assign all sql data in (it's part of a wordpress site I'm sticking together)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach ($portfolioItems[$i] as $key => $val) {
  if ($val == "") {
    $portfolioItems[$i][$key] = " ";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks - this does the trick. Good to chop my bloated code down !

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `foreach` iteration to accomplish it:

```
foreach ($portfolioItems[$i] as &$value) {
    if($value == "") $value = " ";
}

// Thanks @Mark Baker, I forgot this very important line:
unset($value);
```

Comment: Just for safety, unset($value); after the loop

Comment: @Mark Baker - file that one under the "duh" category. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$portfolioKeys = Array('sector', 'workerone'); // Add all keys to check in here

foreach($portfolioKeys as $key) {
    if ($portfolioItems[$i][$key]) == "") {
       $portfolioItems[$i][$key] = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need the `&` to perform the modification? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @Dan Grossman - Ah, yes, I see. Caffeine levels are hovering around empty at the moment. I glossed right over that little tidbit in this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[how about foreach-looping through your array?](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a nested condition but anyways, it looks like you can (maybe - if those are ALL your elements) do:

```
foreach ($portfolioItems[$i] as $k => $v) {
  $portfolioItems[$i][$k] = ($v == "")? " " : $v;
}
```